# Three.js OrbitControls tween animation to face(front) of the target object

Tags: javascript, animation, three.js, tween.js

When I click a button, I want OrbitControls(camera) be in front of the object(face side) smoothly by using tween.js.

I use this code but find that after changing `controls.target` and panning far from the target object, I only can zoom in a little level, and after I zoom in, I can't pan.

Is there another way to look at a object? Thanks!

```js
var from = {
    x: controls.target.x,
    y: controls.target.y,
    z: controls.target.z
};

var to = {
    x: object.getWorldPosition().x,
    y: object.getWorldPosition().y,
    z: object.getWorldPosition().z
};

var tween = new TWEEN.Tween(from)
    .to(to, 1000)
    .easing(TWEEN.Easing.Quadratic.InOut) // | TWEEN.Easing.Linear.None
    .onUpdate(function () {
        controls.target.set( this.x, this.y, this.z )
    })
    .onComplete(function () {
        controls.target.set( this.x, this.y, this.z )
    })
    .start();
```

Comment: You say the camera should be in the front of an object. Why don't you animate the position of the camera instead? When changing `OrbitControls.target`, the camera won't change its position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following: When the animation starts, disable the controls via `controls.enabled = false;` to prevent any interference with your animation. Next, implement the `onComplete()` callback of one of your tweens like so:

```
.onComplete(function() {

    controls.enabled = true;
    camera.getWorldDirection( lookDirection );
    controls.target.copy( camera.position ).add( lookDirection.multiplyScalar( 10 ) );

})
```

The idea is enabling the controls again, computing the current look direction of your view and then setting a new target for the controls. You can also set a predefined target if you need an exact target spot for each camera position. The value `10` is in world units and determines how far away the target should be along the look direction.

Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ckgo7qu8/

Comment: Could you explain why use `controls.target.copy( camera.position ).add( lookDirection.multiplyScalar( 10 ) );`, please?

Comment: It's necessary to update the target of the controls otherwise your issue won't be solved. The target is just set to the camera position and then translated a certain amount into the look direction. Not doing this will causes your camera to "jump" as soon as the controls are enabled again.